# check property value in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I have currently login User object (userId,organisationId,etc.. ) stored in session by using like this.

```
session.setAttribute("user", LoginUser);
```

Where my LoginUser is User object with detail information.

In my next jsp page, I want to check the user's organisationId by calling from Session.

```
<s:property value="%{#session.user.organisationId}"/>
```

How can I check the `organisationId` in property value is 0 or etc., and do things according to various IDs?

How can I check using c:choose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${user.organizationId == 1}">
        <!-- do something -->
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
        <!-- do something different -->
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: I tried ur code too, always goes to otherwise condition. any ideas?

Comment: try printing its value and debug

Comment: thanks.my bad. I didn't have the right value before checking the condition.

Answer (score 3):

Using JSTL, either `<c:if>` conditional tag:

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.user.organisationId == 0}">

</c:if>
```

Or using `<c:choose>` conditional tag:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.user.organisationId == 0}">
        <!-- true -->
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <!-- false -->
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. I think still something wrong with mine. I used c: choose but, it always goes to otherwise condition. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:if test="#session.user.organisationId == 0">
 <p>I'm Zero.</p>
</s:if>
<s:elseif test="#session.user.organisationId == 1">
 <p>I am One.</p>
</s:elseif>
<s:else>
    <p>I not either of these things.</p>
</s:else>
```

organisationId must be a numeric type.